# Matlab Mex file build: Code change doen't influence the mex file anymore

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, matlab, build, mex

I develop a Matlab mex file on Windows8 with the VS2010 C- Compiler. For a long time, all went well...

But now, the mex file resists every change in the code. No matter which lines of code I change, the mex file stays the same after rebuild. Is this a common error for C programmers? Or maybe only relevant to Matlab Mex compiling?

If tried to...

- add a new line of code, e.g. mexPrintf("test"); -> nothing changes
- comment out some essential lines of code -> nothing changes
- delete the complete code -> compile fails
- delete the mexw64 before compile -> still the new code changes dont apply

Maybe the problem occured because I emptied the /appdata/matlab files. But a restore of the files didn't help.

Best regards

Comment: What about restarting MATLAB? If that doesn't fix the issue, my guess is that you have another mexfile with an identical name that has higher precedence in the MATLAB path. Type `which <mexfilename>` at the command prompt and make sure the file it finds is the one you expect.

Comment: Try `clear <mexfilename>`, then rebuild. Always do `clear mex` or `clear <mexfilename>` before re-building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was another mex file, which had higher precedence in the MATLAB path, as Praetorian suggested. Solved it with rmpath('...'). Thanks for your help.

(Unfortunately, I can't upvote your answer, and have to write this myself to mark my question as answered.)